# Laravel Storage::download DONT work, Storage::get DO work

Tags: laravel

I am trying to download a file from a Laravel API local Storage.

`Storage::get`, `Storage::size` works fine!

`Storage::download` just throws a 500 without any further information.

```php
public function downloadDocument(Request $request)
{
    return Storage::size($request->name_hash);
}
```

name_hash is the correct destination to the file. I get the exact size of it.

when changing it to `Storage::download`, nothing works.

Comment: It's virtually guaranteed that your "500 without any further information" actually has a specific error message / exception data in your logs somewhere.

Comment: If the error message is not written in storage/logs/ folder, make sure that the folder has write-permissions.

Comment: I found the mistake. It was a CORS error.

Comment: But the next problem is here. The download doesnt start. I just see it starting and finishing in the developer tools -> network.

Comment: The console says: ERROR OK in core.js:15714

Comment: If you see it in the developer tools, the download *did* start (and finish). Fix your JavaScript error?

Comment: I cant really fix it. It just says: "Ok". I start the download in my Angular 7 Frontend. Maybe there is the mistake? Can i start a download in laravel from the angular frontend like written above?